# Get SharePoint List's Personal Views using PowerShell

Tags: list, powershell, list-view, sharepoint-views

I'm trying to get all names of the personal views created by users for a list.

When I'm using the code

```
$views = $list.views
foreach($view in $views){
   Write-Host $view.Title       
}
```

It only lists the Public views so there is no point in using the condition **$view.PersonalView**.

Is there any way I can list all the views, including personal and public ones and then filter for only the personal ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried what @gautam-sheth has suggested... It may work although I assume you are running as an admin anyway?

Anyway what does work for me is to get the SPSite object with a user token as in the following function:

```
function Get-SPSiteWithToken {
    param (
        [string]$spSite,
        [string]$spweb,
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserToken]$userToken,
        [string]$spList
    )
    $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($spSite, $userToken)
    $web = $site.OpenWeb($spWeb)
    $list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($spList)
    if ($list) {
        foreach ($view in $list.views) {
            if ($view.PersonalView) {
                Write-Host $view.Title
                #Do some stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You then need to call it from something like:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint/site/web
foreach ($user in $web.Users) {
    if (!$user.IsDomainGroup) {
        Get-SPSitewithToken "http://sharepoint/sites/sitecollection" "/relativeUrl/to/web" $user.UserToken "TargetListName"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Run with elevated priviledges as below:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({ 
        $url = "https://sitecollectionurl"
        $web = Get-SPWeb -identity $url
        $list = $web.Lists["CustomList"]
        $viewCollection = $list.Views
        foreach($view in $viewCollection)
        {
            if($view.PersonalView)
            {
                Write-host "Personal View " + $view.Title 
            }
            else
            {
                Write-host "Public View " + $view.Title 
            }
        }    
});
```

Comment: No luck, it still shows only the views created by the System Admin Account.